# UNIQUE ,INDEX AND IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am stuck. I use the import range to get a set of data however now I need to the unique values that that matches the import range that I have.

Say for example below is randome sample. I have import range the information but now I need to find the grades for Book 1. Since there are multiple grades reading book 1, what formula do I use to find the grades(Is it unique(filter(importrange?) and possibly have them in one row and how do I find this for each book?
Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please edit your question and provide a sample sheet. Your image does NOT relate to your question.

Comment: Provide specific: sample data, desired output, & formula of your currently failing output.

Answer (score 0):

You have grade reading data sourced from another spreadsheet using `IMPORTRANGE`. You want to use that data to analyse the books being read by grade.

There are many ways to achieve this outcome. This answer covers the basics of two methods.

Assume that we have data in a spreadsheet, and this data is imported into the current spreadsheet using `IMPORTRANGE`.

[image: ImportRange]

**Option 1 - Create a "table" of data**

### [image: Table of data]

This approach uses two formulas in two adjacent columns:

- `=UNIQUE(D6:D)`: returns unique Grades
- `=JOIN(", ",unique(FILTER($A$6:$A,$D$6:$D=G20)))`: filters Column A (Book id) and Column D (Grade) and returns results where the grade equals the unique grade number in the adjacent cell

---

**Option 2 - Pivot Table**

[image: Pivot table]

In this example:

- Rows: 'Grades', ascending
- Columns: 'Book id' , ascending
- value: Count of the Book id

  If the value isn't important, thern you could "hide" the count by formatting the text colour the same as the background colour.

[image: Pivot table counts hidden]

Comment: Thank you so much. I wan't sure if I was being clear in my question but this was basically it.!...I was able to figure this out using JOINTEXT but yes JOIN also works as well.

Comment: We have a thing in NSW called "The Premier's Reading Challenge"; this is the sort of thing that would/could be produced in/for a school to show the variety and popularity of books, and the range of reading ability for children in each grade.